# Upload file with ADODB for Web-DAV "cannot find any objects or data in accordance with the name..."

Tags: ms-access, vba, adodb

I have an MS Access 2007 VBA application running on Windows 7. One crucial function is to upload files to a WebDAV server. The code below works perfectly on one PC, but fails on other PCs (and yes, each is configured the same way).

Here is a translate.google.com translation of the Norwegion error message that pops up when it fails on the other PCs:

`Run-time error '-2147217895 (80040e19)': can not find any objects or data in accordance with the name, range or selection criteria within the scope of this operation`

It fails on this line of code:

`objRecord.Open fil, "URL=" & URL, adModeReadWrite, adCreateOverwrite, adDelayFetchStream, sUsername, sPwd`

The full function code is below.  It's really just reuse of the code at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/isvvba/thread/26b8e905-33d0-438b-98a7-bb69053b931e/.  Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

```
Function DAVPUT(ByVal URL As String, ByVal fil As String) As Boolean '
    Dim sUsername As String
    Dim sPwd As String
    sUsername = "k@dummy.com"
    sPwd = "dummy"

    Dim objRecord As New ADODB.Record
    Dim objStream As New ADODB.Stream

    objRecord.Open fil, "URL=" & URL, adModeReadWrite, adCreateOverwrite, adDelayFetchStream, sUsername, sPwd
    objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    objStream.Open objRecord, adModeWrite, adOpenStreamFromRecord
    objStream.LoadFromFile fil 
    objStream.Flush
    DoEvents
    objStream.close
    objRecord.close

    DAVPUT = True

End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/56092-ado-stream-error-please-help) suggests you "compare the versions of MDAC local and remote".  I realize I am offering a minimal, inexpert answer, but since there are not others, here it is.